# Optimise use of hardware under Mac + Windows in virtual machine

Tags: windows, hardware, memory, parallels-desktop, cpu

I use a macbook pro with `OS X El Capitan 10.11.4`, `2,5 GHz Intel Core i7` and `8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3`.

I need to code in Visual Studio and use Microsoft Excel for Windows, thus I installed `Parallels Desktop 11 for Mac Business Edition Vestion 11.2.0`, installed `Windows 10` and `Visual Studio 2015`. Here is the setting of Parallels Desktop:

[image]

So now i am working on the 2 operation systems, i feel the CPU is quite occupied; from time to time the fan has to work, the laptop surface is hot, and the whole systems do not feel very fast.

Does anyone have any idea to improve the situation? Is there a way to diagnostic which software is costly? Or do i have to buy another machine for coding under Windows?

Comment: If speed is a problem, why not just install Windows as a separate operating system. I am running 64 bit Windows 10 and using Visual Studio for C++ programming. My computer is a 2007 iMac. This would be impossible if I was running Windows in a virtual machine such as VirtualBox.

Comment: That's a good idea... which software do you use to make Windows work on your mac?

Comment: The software to make Windows work on my mac is the Windows 10 iso file and the "Boot Camp Support Software" provided for free by Apple. Most people install Windows by using the Boot Camp assistant application that comes with OS X. I do not use this application because officially Apple does not support Windows 10 on 2007 Macs. There really is no difference between installing Windows on a Mac and any other Intel/AMD based PC. The Boot Camp Assistant just preforms most of the tedious steps for you. By the way, when was your Mac made? Select "About this Mac" from the menu bar to answer this.

Comment: it was made "Late 2011"

Comment: Since your model does not officially support Windows 10, there in no guarantee that any procedure that I post would work. You would have to try the procedure to find out. Let me put it this way, if you had a Apple supported version of Windows installed and used the Microsoft free upgrade to Windows 10, there is a very good chance of success. The only different here is that you will be doing a clean install instead of an upgrade. The main question is: Does your optical drive work?

Comment: My optical drive works... I have not tried yet Boot Camp (because i need to buy a USB drive), so you are saying that it would not work for me to install Windows 8 (which will be upgraded to Windows 10) with Boot Camp?

Comment: If your Mac has an optical drive, then most likely you will need to use the drive to install Windows. If you do not have a blank DVD, I would suggest purchasing a RW DVD. It takes longer to burn, but is reusable. You will still need a USB flash drive to store the "Boot Camp Support Software" . You install this software after Windows installs. I assumed you already have a license for Widows 10. If so, there is no need to buy a Windows 8 license. But, your are correct. You could install Windows 8 using the Boot Camp Assistant and then upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: Boot Camp Assistant was really scary, see my [post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237722/after-stuck-partitioning-disk-by-boot-camp)...

Comment: You didn't mention *which* model MBP you're using, but if it's a 15 inch model, running a VM causes the discrete graphics to kick in, which produces a LOT of heat, and always makes the fans spin up on my 2011 15" system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling takes CPU even if pure OSX so in a VM will take all the CPU. Fan working and hot is not an issue - it will happen (try compiling gcc under OSX on an i7 CPU all 8 threads will be running for several minutes) I would although give more memory to the VM

To see what is taking CPU you need to look at Activity Monitor in OSX (which will show Parallels taking up a lot of CPU) and Task Manager(I might have forgotten the correct name) in Windows to show what the VM is spending its time on

Comment: Could add that OP can reduce the number of CPU cores available to the VM, if they would like to trade outright speed for cooler temperatures and/or longer battery life