# After stuck "Partitioning disk" by Boot Camp

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, disk-utility, partition

I use a MacBook Pro Late 2011 with OS X El Capitan (10.11.4).

I wanted to install Windows using `Boot Camp Assistant`. **However, I got stuck at `Partitioning disk...`.** It seems that it is a very common problem, and there are many threads on the web concerning this. Here is the screenshot I took while stuck:

[image]

So I had to Force Quit Boot Camp Assistant, and restarted my machine. I checked `Disk Utility`, it seems that I have not lost the 100GB I reserved for Windows, it is still in the available 133.05GB. Besides, I am not observing any abnormal behaviour of my system so far.

[image]
[image]

**Does anyone know what I should do to make sure everything regarding the disk is fine (I don't see `Repair` in Disk Utility)?**

The partitioning thing freaks me out. Is there any expert who knows what to do with Boot Camp Assistant if I still want to install Windows?

**Edit 1:**
Following the suggestion of the comment,

1) `diskutil verifyvolume disk0` on a terminal returns

```
Error starting file system verification for disk0: Invalid request (-69886)
```

2) `diskutil verifyvolume disk1` on a terminal returns the follows:

```
Started file system verification on disk1 Macintosh HD
Verifying storage system
Checking volume
disk0s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk0s2: Scan for Disk Labels
Logical Volume Group 6CF2AE08-886C-4B33-8EC1-3395CC80B6C7 on 1 device
disk0s2: Scan for Metadata Volume
Logical Volume Group has a 24 MB Metadata Volume with double redundancy
Start scanning metadata for a valid checkpoint
Load and verify Segment Headers
Load and verify Checkpoint Payload
Load and verify Transaction Segment
Incorporate 0 newer non-checkpoint transactions
Load and verify Virtual Address Table
Load and verify Segment Usage Table
Load and verify Metadata Superblock
Load and verify Logical Volumes B-Trees
Logical Volume Group contains 1 Logical Volume
Load and verify 7F2AFA2C-C0DE-4D0C-A855-7B1FA17B62D9
Load and verify 25A6AAE1-11B9-4661-AD24-DA9D08EF454D
Load and verify Freespace Summary
Load and verify Block Accounting
Load and verify Live Virtual Addresses
Newest transaction commit checkpoint is valid
Load and verify Segment Cleaning
The volume 6CF2AE08-886C-4B33-8EC1-3395CC80B6C7 appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Verifying file system
Using live mode
Performing live verification
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume
Checking extents overflow file
Checking catalog file
Checking multi-linked files
Checking catalog hierarchy
Checking extended attributes file
Checking volume bitmap
Checking volume information
File system check exit code is 0
Finished file system verification on disk1 Macintosh HD
```

Comment: If you can not get the Boot Camp Assistant to partition your disk, then try using the Disk Utility application. You need to create a MSDOS(FAT) formatted partition named BOOTCAMP. Choose your size carefully. If you need to resize this partition later, you find this to be extremely difficult without the use of third party tools. If you can get past this hurdle, the rest is fairly easy.

Comment: It also appears you are using core storage. This added level of complexity is not required unless you have a Fusion drive or need encryption.

Comment: Thank you... Before partitioning (again) my disk, is there any way to make sure that the previous interruption of partitioning by Boot Camp did not cause any damage and my current disk is all right?

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question. I will try to answer as a comment. Boot to your recovery partition or use internet recovery. Open Disk Utility, select volume, click on Info button, record BSD device node and close Disk Utility. From menu bar open Terminal application, enter `diskutil  verifyvolume  diskx` where `diskx` is the recorded BSD device node. If repair is needed, backup important files. To repair, either: Enter command `diskutil  repairvolume  diskx` or the following. Quit Terminal, open Disk Utility, highlight volume and select "First Aid" button.

Comment: I added the result of `diskutil verifyvolume` in OP: i guess for `disk0` the result is normal?; for `disk1`, it looks good...

Comment: For the `core storage`, is it because I have installed `Parallels Desktop`? In this case, can I still partition my disk (with Disk Utility)?

Comment: The images you posted show `disk0` to be a physical disk and `disk1` to be the volume "Macintosh HD". Running `diskutil verifyvolume` on a disk should produce an error message. I have not used Parallels, but I do not think it is requires core storage. You can partition and install Windows on disks using core storage.